# Box2d javascript add images to bodies and manage art assets

Tags: javascript, canvas, box2d, game-development, box2dweb

```
    OK so I have a few levels of a simple platform built out,
```

so I just need some insight on how to assign images to bodies, and handle images, etc.  The game is a simple platform game, with a ball as the palyer chacter and
 you have to try to reach the other side.  I have some obstacles like
 joints and swinging balls, etc.  Just getting it started, please let
 me know if you can help... box2dweb.. Here is an example of a few 
bodies inside my game in various places.. Any advice would be greatly
 appreciated. Pplayer character let me know if you can help.

```
function PC(gamePiece){
        if (gamePiece == 1) {
        var ballSd1 = new b2CircleDef();
            ballSd1.density = 1.1;
            ballSd1.radius = 22;
            ballSd1.restitution = 0.5;
            ballSd1.friction = 1;
            ballSd1.userData = 'player';
            var ballBd = new b2BodyDef();
            ballBd.linearDamping = .03;
            ballBd.allowSleep = false;
            ballBd.AddShape(ballSd1);
            ballBd.position.Set(40,0);
            player.object = world.CreateBody(ballBd);   
        }
```

ok so i am using box2d and need some help adding images to bodies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you do not generate your world programmatically. You will need to find an editor suitable for this job, or write one yourself.

I can advice you to use [R.U.B.E](https://www.iforce2d.net/rube/) which lets you create your Box2D worlds and attach images to the bodies. You may then export the scene via JSON which fits very well to javascript.

The rendering of those images attached to bodies will be a custom job. As well as the importing of the scene if there is no loader for box2dweb yet.